# Tomcat 6 - connectTimeout still executing default

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration

I have a Servlet that is requested via JQuery Ajax. The process that is activated takes a good bit of time to execute (up to 3-5 mins). I have set the connectTimeout in the  in server.xml to "600000" (10 mins), but it seems like Tomcat is ignoring it. Consistently it returns a 504 Bad Gateway at the one minute mark. Is there another setting that I need to adjust to make connectTimeout work? The snippet from my server.xml is below.

```
<Connector port="8080" 
    executor="tomcatThreadPool" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="600000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Are you reverse proxying with anything or connecting directly to Tomcat?

Comment: I am connecting directly to Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Tomcat is not the cause of the timeout you are experiencing. A "504 Gateway Timeout" error is most often caused by a gateway/proxy/firewall somewhere between you and Tomcat.

Comment: Good suggestion, had similar problem and your answer reminded me I'm proxing the requests behind Nginx.